# Telegram API code is no longer sending messages

Tags: .net, ssl, model-view-controller, telegram, webapi

Telegram API/BOT code is no longer sending messages and getting the following error

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I also tried the following option

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

API/BOT is working locally as expected but when I hosted the application in live server (Bigrock shared hosting) am getting this issue. Tried in both secure & non-secure environments

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. "Working in dev but not in live"
Found this: https://clickalgo.com/telegram-secure-channel 
Worked for me, you probably just need to run it before you create the bot.
Example from site:

[image]

Comment: yes its working in Console app, but if you convert this into ASP.Net Web App its not working. Web App also locally working perfectly **but in shared hosting it is not working**.

Comment: @Kiran. So I'm no expert but perhaps I can point you in the right direction. When using ASP.net you run different sessions and nothing is static. The session is only open while a call is being made or its timed out by your web-server(Probably IIS). IIS express which you use to debug works differently and is probably the reason why it worked locally. As far as I am aware best practice is to run a separate service for processes you do not want to get killed I.E Telegram Bot.